# Magento 2 Get Order Data In Order Email Confirmation Template

Tags: magento2, email, sales-order, email-templates, order-grid

I have made a custom template to use in my order confirmation email template.

I want to get the order data in this template so I can create a custom order grid layout.

I'm not sure on how to do this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please share your custom template

Answer (score 1):

Did you check how Magento default templates works?

e.g. Magento_Sales/view/frontend/email

This is an example how to get customer name in email template:

```
<h1 class="greeting">{{trans "Hello %name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getName()}}</h1>
```

Comment: Yeah I have, doesn't really help as that code is generated by Magento. I need to pull the order data manually so I can create a custom layout.

Comment: Please share more details in your answer like steps.

Answer (score 0):

To get order details

```
<h1 class="greeting">{{trans "Hello %name,"
name=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}}</h1>
```